# Where are variable names stored in a C++ program？

Tags: c++, variables

For example,I define a variable

```
int a=5;
```

I know the `5` is stored in the stack, but where is `a` stored?
Please help

Comment: The value of `a` is stored in memory. But the variable name itself isn't stored anywhere. The code generated by the compiler will know the address (location in memory) of the variable and will use that instead.

Comment: Usually they aren't. Those names are for us humans. The computer will turn it into an address or an offset from an address. Usually those nice human readable names are among the first things to go during compilation. There may be debug information stored in the file or as a supplementary file, but all bets are off.

Comment: No you don't know if its stored on the stack, it could just as well be put in a register (optimizations). Live demo here :  https://godbolt.org/z/8YGnec36h. Now what is your real question?

Comment: The name may be stored for debug reasons, but this is optional. Typically the binary file contains a section with debug info where names, source locations and data types are collected. But as said, only as an option. But object files need to know the names as long they are not finally linked to get symbols requested from other files to link resolved.

Comment: Handy way of thinking about code: It's not a list of instructions for the computer to run. It is a description of the behaviour you want the program to have. The compiler will take that description of behaviour and turn it into the best, most efficient list of instructions for the computer that it can come up with in the constraints you give it (optimization options selected) and how good the compiler is at its job. You probably won't be able to recognize the code after the compiler's done with it. This is normal. Practically no one can.

Answer (score 3):

> Where are variable names stored in a C++ program？

The variable names are stored in the source code.

The details of the produced program are outside the scope of the language, but typically, the variable names are stored - if they are stored at all - in "debug information".

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete minimal example that demonstrates @eerorika's answer about the debug information (here, in ELF files):

```
$ cat main.cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int whereIsMyVar = 5;
    return whereIsMyVar;
}
```

And compiling it *without* optimizations (`-O0`), and *with* debug info (`-g`):

```
$ g++ -g -O0 main.cpp -o main
```

Now let's see what went on with `objdump`:

```
$ objdump -D -S main > main.asm
$ sed -n "378,389p" main.asm
00000000000005fa <main>:
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 5fa:   55                      push   %rbp
 5fb:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 5fe:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
 601:   48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
    int whereIsMyVar = 5;
 605:   c7 45 fc 05 00 00 00    movl   $0x5,-0x4(%rbp) <--- there is your assignment !
    return whereIsMyVar;
 60c:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
}
```

Now let's use the `addr2line` utility to easily extract the source code location corresponding to this address:

```
$ addr2line -e main 0x605
/home/oren/main.cpp:3
```

And finally, let's see what's on line 3 of our source file [[ drumroll ]]:

```
$ sed -n "3,3p" /home/oren/main.cpp
    int whereIsMyVar = 5;
```

So as you can see, the name `whereIsMyVar` is connected via file name + line
to its original source file location.

Answer (score 0):

The variables names are non-existent after the compilation process(Exceptions: global variables in shared libs).
The whole idea is to convert your source code to machine instructions.

```
int a = 5;
```

Assuming this is your global variable, it will be assigned a address in memory let's say 0xFFFFFFFF, by the compiler and linker & henceforth, all actions done pertaining to this variable (read/write/modify), will be done via accessing that address.

Comment: Shared libs are no exception. Variables names having external linkage have to subsist up to the link phase. The particularity of shared libs is that the link phase occur just before the execution.